# Whittaker function oscillation on diagonal near 0

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

In Proposition 1 of [Blomer - Applications of the Kuznetsov formula on GL(3)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1781), bounds are given for the Whittaker function
$$W_{\nu_1, \nu_2}(y_1, y_2) = \mathcal W_{\nu_1, \nu_2}\begin{pmatrix} y_1y_2 &&\\ &y_1&\\ && 1\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\mathcal W$ is given by (2.10) in the Blomer paper.
In particular, it is shown that for fixed $\nu_1$, $\nu_2$ (assuming that $\theta = 0$ in the notation of Proposition 1),
$$\lvert W(y_1, y_2)\rvert\ll_{\nu_1, \nu_2} (y_1y_2)^{1 - o(1)}$$
for small $y_1$, $y_2$. Are there any asymptotics for this quantity for $y_1$, $y_2$ small?

Comment: You should be able to get asymptotics by looking at equation (2.15) and shifting the contours to the left. The poles at $s_1 = -\alpha_j$ and $s_2 = \alpha_j$ give the leading order terms in the asymptotic expansion about $(y_1,y_2) = (0,0)$.

Comment: For spherical Whittaker function on $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such asymptotics can be read off from Thereom 7.8 in Hashizume's paper "Whittaker functions on semisimple Groups."